# Could not bootstrap with CCCP : Couchbase memcached bucket exception

Tags: c#, couchbase

I'm using the latest version of CouchbaseNetClient NuGet package 2.7.4 to connect Couchbase 4.6.3 enterprise version(running on docker in my laptop).
C# Code :

```
var config = new ClientConfiguration
            {
                // assign one or more Couchbase Server URIs available for bootstrap
                Servers = new List<Uri>
                {
                    new Uri("http://192.168.99.100:8091/")
                },
                BucketConfigs = new Dictionary<string, BucketConfiguration> {
                    {"memcachetest", new BucketConfiguration {
                        PoolConfiguration = new PoolConfiguration {
                            MaxSize = 6,
                            MinSize = 4,
                            SendTimeout = 12000
                        },
                        Port = 8091,
                        DefaultOperationLifespan = 123,
                        Password = "",
                        Username = "",
                        BucketName = "memcachetest"
                    }}},
                UseSsl = false,
            };
            ClusterHelper.Initialize(config);
```

This code works fine for the normal bucket(sample bucket below) but I'm unable to connect to Memcached(memcachetest) bucket. 
[image: couchbase buckets]

Following line throws all sorts of exception while opening the bucket.

```
private readonly IBucket _bucket = ClusterHelper.GetBucket("memcachetest", "");
```

[image: exception]

I have tried with/without passwords. It's all over my head now from the last 2 days! Any help appriciated!!

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to use memcache bucket instead of a Couchbase bucket?

Answer (score 4):

Memcached buckets don't support CCCP. The client will first try CCCP and then move to HTTP Streaming when CCCP fails - this gets logged and probably what you stumbled onto. Since it's an AggregateException, it appears that there may be other reasons why its failing - you'll have to look into each exception for the reason. Note you can skip CCCP for Memcached buckets by setting ConfigurationProviders to HttpStreaming:

```
ClientConfiguration.ConfigurationProviders = ServerConfigurationProviders.HttpStreaming;
```

Comment: its the problem with docker instance of couchbase server. may I need to enable ports on dicker container which are used by memcache bucket